# Standard methods for documenting a RESTful API

Tags: rest, documentation

I'm writing a specification for a RESTful API for a new internal web service. It's not hugely long and fairly simple, but even so, it's my first time using strict REST (as opposed to cheating for practical reasons - avoiding `PUT` and `DELETE` because they're a pain in PHP, and so on). I was wondering if there were any standard methods or best practices for documenting a REST interface? I want the rest of the team to understand it at a glance, and for anyone that wants to write a client to be able to do so without understanding the underlying code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful API Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966243/restful-api-documentation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966243/restful-api-documentation)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sure, [REST APIs should ideally use HATEOAS and be hypertext driven](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/rest-hypermedia-hateoas) (with heavy use of media types), but also having simple human-friendly documentation for developers to work off of is helpful.

Some specific tools that are helpful for generating documentation like this:

- [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger)

  - An open spec for describing REST APIs [ [github](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec) ]
  - Tools for auto-generating

    - Documentation
    - Code for your API
  - Donated to the OpenAPI initiative and [renamed OpenAPI in 2015](https://swagger.io/blog/difference-between-swagger-and-openapi/)
- [Mashery](http://support.mashery.com/docs/read/IO_Docs)

  - An open source project [ [github](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs) ]
  - Tools for generating

    - Documentation
    - An exploration interface for your API
- [Apiary](http://apiary.io/how-it-works) and [API Blueprint](http://apiblueprint.org/)

  - Write the API description in a DSL within markdown
  - Tools for auto-generating

    - Documentation
    - Mock server
  - *Seems to be focused on ruby+mac devs*
- [RAML](http://raml.org/)

  - A spec for describing REST APIs [ [github](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec) ]
- [WADL](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/)

  - A spec for writing discoverable API docs with XML
  - Some discussion [comparing WSDL and WADL](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/documenting-rest-services-wsdl-and-wadl.html)
- [APIgee](http://apigee.com/docs/developer-services/content/using-smartdocs-document-apis)

  - A commercial product with some documentation features
- [3scale](http://www.3scale.net/)

  - A commercial product with some documentation features
- [miredot](http://www.miredot.com/)

  - Commercial REST API documentation generator
  - Java specific

Comment: you should also add miredot http://www.miredot.com to the list

Comment: @java_geek Sure, thanks for the rec. Feel free to edit if you find more.

Comment: Conversions between API-description formats are also worth noting, for example https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter and http://studio.restlet.com/

Answer (score 13):

I've been using http://apiary.io, which is pretty nice. You can also export the API documentation to github.

Comment: Isn't it documenting how to build URIs ? .. which sounds against HATEOAS ?

Answer (score 9):

In Roy's post [here](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) he states

> A REST API should spend almost all of
>   its descriptive effort in defining the
>   media type(s) used for representing
>   resources and driving application
>   state, or in defining extended
>   relation names and/or
>   hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing
>   standard media types. Any effort spent
>   describing what methods to use on what
>   URIs of interest should be entirely
>   defined within the scope of the
>   processing rules for a media type
>   (and, in most cases, already defined
>   by existing media types).

Comment: I think that what you're saying is that the API should be self-documenting and logical enough not to need documentation. That's fair enough. However, somewhere along the line, I'm going to need to give people a list of allowed calls at the very least. I want to know if there's some sort of accepted structure for said list.

Comment: No.  Media-types definitely need documentation.  Here are a bunch of examples http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/
What your documentation should not include is a list of URLs.  That will just encourage client developers to hardcode those urls into their application.

Comment: Maybe I can make up a useful example.  Imagine going to a foreign country where you do not speak the language and going to a library to look for some information.  Imagine if you asked for help and the person explained to you the concept of a bookshelf, ISBN cataloging, that books contained pages and you read the book from front to back.  All valid information but you already know that.  You need someone to translate the content.  On the web we know about Urls and hyperlinks, we know how to use HTTP verbs.  We just need to understand the details of your content.

Comment: Gotcha. This was my gut feeling too: provide detailed explanations of what each call *does*, not what it *is*. I'm thinking there isn't a standard method for doing this, but hell, I guess winging it never hurt anybody (don't quote me on that). Thanks for your help.

Comment: So say someone wants to use your API and is unable to access the source code, how would they know what fields are required for POSTing a new "student" for example?

Comment: @NickCoad Your server could teach its clients how to construct a valid Student by returning a `template` property (which outlines the required/accepted fields), as part of its response to GET requests. The client could then parse this template to learn how to create a well-formed Student before POSTing back to the server.

Comment: @Mark So you would only be able to develop for each endpoint by actually querying the endpoint first and then writing your own documentation to describe the endpoint? That doesn't seem very user friendly.

Answer (score 6):

A good ReST documentation would mean documenting your media type and only your media type.

In a typical scenario, you'd produce a document like so:

### The Acme Corp XML formats

#### Link Discovery

Links to various resources are described in a document that can be found by issuing a GET or HEAD request to the server on a bookmark URI (typically the root of the server, http://www.acme.org), and looking for an HTTP Link header:

`Link: <xxx>;rel="http://rel.acme.org/services";type=application/vnd.acme.services+xml`

where the `rel` part is the link relationship, and the `xxx` is the URI for which the relationship has been established.

### Link Relationships

This document defines the following relationship names:

- http://rel.acme.org/services
  The link relationship describes the list of links that can be navigated.
- http://rel.acme.org/customers
  The link for which this relationship is used is the list of customers.

### Media Types

The `application/vnd.acme.services+xml` is a document with an `xml` serialization that describes a list of links an application may want to process.

```xml
<links>
 <link rel="http://rel.acme.org/customers" href="http://www.acme.org/services/customers" type="application/vnd.acme.customers+xml" />
</link>
```

The `applcation/vnd.acme.customers+xml` is a document with an `xml` serialization that describes customers.

#### Example documents:

```xml
<customers>
 <customer firstname="Darth" lastname="Vador" href="http://www.acme.org/services/customers/28" />
</customer>
```

etc...

The point is to give a way to the developer to follow the links you define. First find the link to the *index* so they can get the list of things they can navigate to.

Once they discover that document, they discover that they can see a list of customers at a certain Uri, and can do a `GET` against it.

If they find a customer of interest, they can follow the link defined in `/customers/customer/@href` and issue a `GET` to retrieve a representation of that customer.

From there, your media type could embed actions that are available to the user, using more links. You also have the additional option of issuing an OPTIONS request on the resource to know if you can allow deleting the resource, or a PUT if you can save the document back after modification.

So a good documentation doesn't ever:

- give static links
- give interaction such as "you can issue POST on Customer with this media type and that will mean the move operation". The client should issue a POST against Customer only because your XML document has specified it that way.

The point of all this is to achieve minimum coupling between clients and servers. The client can be very smart in displaying and discovering resources (showing forms and god knows what else), but is totally dumb as to what the actual workflow is: the server decides.

Comment: OK, so I should mainly be using link discovery to document the API. How exactly do I construct such an XML document? Got any links?

Comment: Yes, you would document how to discover links and actions in your media type.

As for how to do it, have a look at ATOM and HTML, that's pretty much all you need: a <link rel= href=> and some way to convey an action that you want to display in your client.

Answer (score 5):

At my company, we've been very happy using [WADL](https://wadl.dev.java.net/), Web Application Description Language. Wikipedia [describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) it as: "an XML-based file format that provides a machine-readable description of HTTP-based web applications". I find raw WADL easy to write, read, and understand, and it maps directly to RESTful concepts. The official project provides a simple spec, XSD and RELAX NG schemata, and Java tools.

A number of tools and resources exist for working with WADL, including:

- [wadl_stylesheets](http://github.com/mnot/wadl_stylesheets/tree/master), XSLT stylesheets to create HTML documentation from WADL files
- [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org), a Java framework for building RESTful servers and clients, includes a WADL extension

A tip: try including human-readable documentation, such as descriptions, concepts, getting started, usage tips, etc, in the WADL document's `doc` element by including HTML elements, using the XHTML namespace. It can make a big difference!

Comment: An ongoing discussion in Rest-discuss [1] shows that a number of REST advocates see little advantage to using WADL.

[1] http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/12680

Comment: I've looked into WADL, but it seems that it's more oriented towards machine interpretation rather than documentation. I don't need to tell the computer how to deal with the API - that only needs to be written once. I do need to tell people how to write clients, and so people are my primary audience.

Comment: You can also generate client side stubs with WADL, for strongly typed languages.  E.g. see wadl2java

Answer (score 3):

You might find [rest-tool](http://tombenke.github.io/rest-tool/index.html) useful.

It follows a language agnostic approach to write specification, mock implementation and automated unit-testing for RESTful APIs. It also provides a cook-book however it is in a very early stage, but its content is continuously growing.

The services you just described can be immediately used, so it is also good for experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, we went for static documentation of resources but just had to field too many questions. Eventually, we moved to using Live documentation pages using IO/Docs (actually a [fork](https://github.com/vkorapaty/iodocs)).
Been working great.

Answer (score 1):

To create understanding/documentation, heavyweight solutions aren't always needed. Examples of (great) heavyweight tools are: IO/Docs / Apigee (although great tools).

For tiny projects that already have a docchain setup (doxygen/phpdoc/phpdoctor/custom/etc) I use the following shellscript to just include the page in the full generated documentation:

https://gist.github.com/4496972

A demo: http://pastie.org/5657190

It just use custom comment-tags in your sourcecode.
It can also be a nice starting point for documenting any sourcecode (language).

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.